# Kubernetes metrics-server: Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request

Tags: kubernetes

executing the command `kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` 
it returned `Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request`

view the logs from metrics-server

`http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.133.64:51926:EOF`

kubelet version is 1.12.3

metrics-server 0.3.1

i have another clusters-set with the same version and configuration, metrics-server works just fine

part of metrics-server-deployment:

 `containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-dir
          mountPath: /tmp`

Comment: Can you show the logs of metrics server by kubectl logs command

Comment: I0111 04:15:03.728375       1 serving.go:273] Generated self-signed cert (apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt, apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key)
[restful] 2019/01/11 04:15:04 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://:443/swaggerapi
[restful] 2019/01/11 04:15:04 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https://:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
I0111 04:15:04.385580       1 serve.go:96] Serving securely on [::]:443
I0111 04:15:14.516202       1 logs.go:49] http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.133.64:60614: EOF

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is failing because the hostname resolution happens through the internal DNS system which have pods/service entries but not cluster node entries.

Try running your metrics-server with following arguments:

```
- command:
  - /metrics-server
  - --kubelet-insecure-tls
  - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

It should work for you as well.

For more info you can look at the following issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/131)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but getting the error : not sure where to add with indentation : admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/poc-cog/metrics-server$ kubectl apply -f deploy/1.8+/metrics-server-deployment.yaml
serviceaccount/metrics-server unchanged
error: error parsing deploy/1.8+/metrics-server-deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 43: found a tab character that violates indentation
 nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
        - command:
          - /metrics-server
          - --kubelet-insecure-tls
          - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP

Answer (score 3):

Also worth pointing out that you should make sure `metric-server` is running

```sh
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep metrics-server
```